# How to project content of component by some statement (e.g. by input value)

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent, ng-content

I'm working on the implementation custom table and faced with an issue.

I cannot correctly project column-component content inside table-component.

- **table.component.ts**:

  ```
  @Component({
      selector: 'app-table',
      template: `
      <table>
      ...
      <tbody>
          <tr
              *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
              <td *ngFor="let column of columns">
                  <ng-container *ngIf="column.key">{{ getCellValue(column.key, row.value) }}</ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="!column.key">
                      <ng-content select="app-column"></ng-content> <!-- [1] this one show content just in last cell -->

                      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="column.contentTemplateRef;"></ng-container> <!-- [2] the same as line above, but another column wrapped in ng-template -->
                  </ng-container>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      ...
      </table>
      `,
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
  })
  export class TableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
      rows: any[];

      @ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => TableColumnComponent))
      columns: QueryList<TableColumnComponent>;

      getCellValue(key: string, row: any): any {
          return key.split('.').reduce((a, b) => a[b], row);
      }

  }
  ```
- **column.component.ts**:

  ```
  @Component({
      selector: 'app-column',
      template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`, // [1]
      // template: `<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>`, // [2]
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
  })
  export class TableColumnComponent {
      @ViewChild(TemplateRef) contentTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>; // [2]
  }
  ```

I've added notes in which situation which template I'm using.

---

In [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dfnmqp?file=src/app/app.component.ts) you can see how it works. The button rendered just in the last cell in the last column, but I expect that all cells from the last column will render buttons.

---

My question is how I could correctly render column content?

Comment: I guess this exact case can not work, because you want to create multiple projections of the same template, each with its own scope.
When you add a Template to a parent, it gets automatically removed from the old parent.